# Change in direction when a line hits an ellipse?

Tags: graphics, regions, rotation, optics

I'm trying to simulate reflecting light off an elliptical mirror.  I currently store the ellipse in the form `{center,{radii},rotationAngle}` and the ray of light is specified by a direction and a starting point: `{direction, pt}`. See below:

[image]

Now I can quite easily find the intersection point using `RegionIntersection`, but what I'm having a hard time doing is finding the *new* direction for the line after it hits the ellipse.  I can do some (ugly) calculations using the parametric form of the ellipse to find the normal line, and then use `ArcTan`, etc. But I'm wondering if there's an elegant and easy way to determine the new direction for the line post-reflection.

Comment: @belisarius: I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: Read the second paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Level_sets) carefully

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77148/reflecting-lines-in-ellipses-speed-up-the-code

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38927/5478

Comment: `Projection[]` will be very useful here.