# Reflecting lines in ellipses: speed up the code?

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, geometry

I have the following code which calculates a list of points that a line would take after bouncing off various ellipses.

```
maxTime = 50; centers = {{0, 0}, {3, 0}};
radii = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}};
angles = {0, Pi/3};
ClearAll[x, y, circleIntersection, nextDirection, nextPt, whichCirc, \
tangentVector]
circleIntersection[direction_, pt_List, 
                   circs_List] := {x, y} //. {ToRules[
 Quiet@Reduce@
   RegionMember[
    RegionIntersection[RegionUnion[circs], 
     Line[{pt, 
       pt + {Cos[direction], Sin[direction]}*{maxTime, 
          maxTime}}]], {x, y}]]};

nextPt[direction_, pt_List] := 
  With[{val = 
   First@PadLeft[
     MinimalBy[EuclideanDistance[pt, #] &]@
      Function[x, Select[x, Abs[EuclideanDistance[pt, #]] > .05 &]]@
       N@circleIntersection[direction, pt, 
        MapThread[
        TransformedRegion[Circle[#1, #2], 
          RotationTransform[#3, #1]] &, {centers, radii, 
         angles}]], 1, pt]}, 
   If[ListQ[val], val, 
       pt + {Cos[direction], Sin[direction]}*{maxTime, maxTime}]];

whichCirc[direction_, pt_List] := 
  First@PadLeft[
    Flatten@Position[
      RegionMember[#, nextPt[direction, pt]] & /@ 
       MapThread[
        TransformedRegion[Circle[#1, #2], 
          RotationTransform[#3, #1]] &, {centers, radii, angles}],
          _?TrueQ, 1, 1], 1];

tangentVector[pt_List, pos_Integer] := 
  Module[{a, b, c, d, e, m, n, s, r, dx, dy}, m = Cos[angles[[pos]]]; 
   n = Sin[angles[[pos]]]; s = radii[[pos]][[2]]; 
   r = radii[[pos]][[1]]; a = s^2*m^2 + r^2*n^2;
   b = s^2*n^2 + r^2*m^2; 
   c = 2 (m*n*r^2*centers[[pos]][[2]] - centers[[pos]][[1]]*n^2*r^2 - 
       centers[[pos]][[1]]*m^2*s^2 - centers[[pos]][[2]]*m*n*s^2); 
   d = 2 (centers[[pos]][[1]]*m*n*r^2 - centers[[pos]][[2]]*m^2*r^2 - 
       centers[[pos]][[1]]*m*n*s^2 - centers[[pos]][[2]]*n^2*s^2); 
   e = -2 (m*n*r^2 - m*n*s^2); dx = 2*a*pt[[1]] + c + e*pt[[2]]; 
   dy = 2*b*pt[[2]] + d + e*pt[[1]]; If[pos > 0, {-dy, dx}]];

 nextDirection[direction_, pt_List, ptnow_List] := 
  With[{pos = whichCirc[direction, ptnow]}, 
   If[pos > 0 && ptnow != pt, 
    ArcTan[Sequence @@ (ReflectionTransform[tangentVector[pt, pos], 
          pt][ptnow] - pt)], direction]];

f1[{dir_, pt_, ___}] := {dir, nextPt[dir, pt], pt};
g1[{dir_, newpt_, pt_}] := {nextDirection[dir, newpt, pt], newpt, pt};

ellipsePtList[dir_, startPt_, mt_] := 
 Module[{timeUpYet, len = 0}, 
  timeUpYet[pt1_, pt2_] := 
   Module[{dist = EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]}, len += dist; 
    Return[len < mt]]; 
  Flatten[NestWhileList[g1[f1[#]] &, {dir, startPt}, 
     timeUpYet[#1[[2]], #2[[2]]] &, 2][[All, 2 ;; 2]], 1]]
```

It allows me to do the following:

```
With[{dir = 0, pt = {0.6, 0.3}}, 
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[ellipsePtList[dir, pt, maxTime]], Blue, 
   MapThread[
    GeometricTransformation[Circle[#1, #2], 
      RotationTransform[#3, #1]] &, {centers, radii, angles}]}]]
```

[image: output]

Which produces a very nice picture, but takes about 5 seconds on my computer to run.  So I'm looking for ways to speed this code up.  After some preliminary testing, it seems the `whichCirc` function is the bottleneck (but I will take optimizations for any part of the code).  Any and all suggestions are most welcome!

**PS** - sorry for the code formatting above, it's hard to paste in a lot of code and make it nice!

**EDIT**: there was some confusion over exactly what was being asked.  I need this to work in the generality that there could be several ellipses, positioned in various ways.  For example, changing the first few lines above to:

```
maxTime = 100; centers = {{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {0, 0}};
radii = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {6, 6}};
angles = {0, Pi/3, 0};
```

and then executing the same code at the bottom (with different start point):

```
With[{dir = 0, pt = {1.6, 0.5}}, 
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[ellipsePtList[dir, pt, maxTime]], Blue, 
   MapThread[
    GeometricTransformation[Circle[#1, #2], 
      RotationTransform[#3, #1]] &, {centers, radii, angles}]}]]
```

gives the final picture:

[image]

Comment: related: [38927](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38927/5478)

Comment: Also related (and unanswered): [(73512)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73512/121)

Comment: @Kuba: I looked at your code, and it definitely helps.  But it is different than what I'm trying to do: I'd like a list of points (up to some length) visited by the bouncing particle, and I'd also like to do the computations for when the particle *hits* the boundary, not when it gets sufficiently close.

Comment: The title of the question contains "in ellipses" - but that's misleading if you want to allow *exterior* reflections.

Comment: Also related (but still just one curve): [63690](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63690/oval-or-bunimovich-stadium)

Comment: @Jens: fair enough, though the first sentence mentions "bouncing off". :) The main point though is that the configuration of ellipses is random (but fixed), and the start point of the line is determined dynamically (which is why I need the generality).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update

The original approach for one ellipse (below) may be adapted for several:

```
eq = With[{p = {x, y} - {x0, y0}},
    (RotationMatrix[-t0].p).{{1/a^2, 0}, {0, 1/b^2}}.(RotationMatrix[-t0].p)] - 1;
sub[pt_] := Thread[{x, y} -> pt];
dir[t0_] := {Cos[t0], Sin[t0]};

ClearAll[next, cuts];
Block[{a, b, t0, x0, y0, x1, y1, α, x, y, t, ellipses}, 
  next = With[{sol = Simplify[
        t /. Solve[eq == 0 /. sub[{x1, y1} + t dir[α]], t], 
        TimeConstraint -> 0.1]}, 
    With[{x2 = x /. sub[{x1, y1} + t dir[α]], 
      y2 = y /. sub[{x1, y1} + t dir[α]]}, 
     With[{θ = ArcTan[D[eq, x], D[eq, y]] /. sub[{x2, y2}]},
      (* definitions using above algebra *)
      cuts[sect_][ell_] := sect /. Thread[{a, b, t0, x0, y0} -> ell];
      Function @@ Hold[{ellipses, x1, y1, α},
        With[{sects = cuts[sol] /@ ellipses},
         t = First@Sort@Select[Chop@Flatten[sects], Positive]; {x2, y2, 
           Mod[2 θ - α + Pi, 2 Pi]} /. 
          Thread[{a, b, t0, x0, y0} -> ellipses~Part~First@FirstPosition[sects, t]
         ]
        ]
      ]]]
  ];
```

OP's new example:

```
centers = {{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {0, 0}};
radii = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {6, 6}};
angles = {0, Pi/3, 0};
ells = Flatten[{radii, List /@ angles, centers}, {{2}, {1, 3}}];

With[{dir = 0, pt = {1.6, 0.5}}, 
  ptsdir = NestList[
    next[ells, Sequence @@ #] &, {Sequence @@ pt, dir}, 19];
  pts = ptsdir[[All, 1 ;; 2]]; 
  Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[pts], Blue, 
    MapThread[
     GeometricTransformation[Circle[#1, #2], 
       RotationTransform[#3, #1]] &, {centers, radii, angles}]}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With 100 points:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Original answer

I used a cartesian equation of a rotated ellipse and the angle of the normal to compute the reflection.  Replace `Function` by `Compile` if you want more speed, but the figure below is computed in a little over `0.05` sec, most of which time was spent computing the plot of the ellipse.

Given the ellipse `x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1` rotated by an angle `t0`, an initial point `{x0, y0}`, and a direction `α`, the function `next` returns the next intersection and direction in a list `{x1, y1, α1}`.

```
eq = (RotationMatrix[-t0].{x, y}).{{1/a^2, 0}, {0, 1/b^2}}.(RotationMatrix[-t0].{x, y}) - 1;
sub[pt_] := Thread[{x, y} -> pt];
dir[t0_] := {Cos[t0], Sin[t0]};

Block[{a, b, t0, x0, y0, α, x, y, t}, 
  next = (* preliminary algebra *)
   With[{sol = t /. Solve[eq == 0 /. sub[{x0, y0} + t dir[α]], t ] // Simplify},
    With[{x1 = x /. sub[{x0, y0} + t dir[α]], 
      y1 = y /. sub[{x0, y0} + t dir[α]]},
     With[{θ = ArcTan[D[eq, x], D[eq, y]] /. sub[{x1, y1}]}, (* angle of normal *)
       (* function definition *)
      Function @@ Hold[
        {a, b, t0, x0, y0, α},
        t = First@Select[sol, # > 1.*^-8 &];       (* tolerance could be ~1.*^-14 *)
        {x1, y1, Mod[2 θ - α + Pi, 2 Pi]}          (* new x, y, reflected angle *)
        ]
      ]]]
  ];
```

Here `ptsdir` contains a list of `{x, y, theta}` and `pts` contains a list of the points.

```
Block[{a = 4, b = 2, t0 = Pi/6},
 ptsdir = NestList[next[a, b, t0, Sequence @@ #] &, {2., 2., 0.}, 170];
 pts = ptsdir[[All, 1 ;; 2]]; 
 ContourPlot[eq == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[0.001], Line[pts]}]
 ]
```

Comment: I think the example I gave in the question makes it somewhat unclear. But I have *several* ellipses that need to be reflected off of (potentially) .

Comment: @SteveD Yeah, I saw that in your comment to Jens' answer, but I had already solved it this way. I think you could adapt this approach to pick the nearest intersection (smallest positive `t`). The equations are all quadratic, so you can solve them beforehand as I did the one. Then knowing which ellipse was intercepted, you could compute the reflected angle.  Given the image in your question, it's not clear what sort of configurations we'd have to worry about.

Comment: @Jens I suppose my answer will work on any algebraic equation for which the solutions returned by `Solve` will always contain exactly one positive solution (and for which the gradient points outward).  Otherwise, one could use `t = First@Sort@Select[Chop@sol, Quiet@TrueQ[# > 0] &]`. Still, I wouldn't expect it to work as well for complicated equations. (+1 to you, too, already.)

Comment: Wow, that is a serious speed improvement! I'm going to accept this answer because it works in the generality I wanted, but I also would like to point out that I've noticed my `NestWhileList` was actually adding to the slow performance of my code. And I noticed that because you used `NestList` instead.  Originally I had been stopping the line when it passed a certain length threshold, but it does seem to slow things up.  Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following functions based on what @Kuba did in his related post:

```
maxTime = 50; centers = {{0, 0}, {3, 0}};
radii = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}};
angles = {0, Pi/3};
circs = MapThread[
   TransformedRegion[Circle[#1, #2], 
     RotationTransform[#3, #1]] &, {centers, radii, angles}];
r = RegionUnion @@ circs;
region = RegionBoundary@DiscretizeRegion@r;
ClearAll[x, y, circleIntersection, nextDirection, nextPt, whichCirc, \
tangentVector]
circleIntersection[direction_, pt_List] := 
  p /. Quiet@
    NSolve[p \[Element] 
      RegionIntersection[r, 
       Line[{pt, 
         pt + {Cos[direction], Sin[direction]}*{maxTime, maxTime}}]], 
     p];
```

and

```
nextDirection[direction_, pt_List, ptnow_List] := 
  Module[{vec, v = {Cos[direction], Sin[direction]}, 
    normal = Normalize[pt - RegionNearest[region, pt]]}, 
   vec = Normalize[v - 2 v.normal normal] + ptnow; 
   If[pt == ptnow, direction, ArcTan[First@vec, Last@vec]]];
```

I saw about a 5x speed-up versus my original code, but something is now wrong: the trajectories are being computed incorrectly (something is off in the tangent vectors). Guidance is most appreciated.