# Ball Bouncing on Hilly Terrain

Tags: differential-equations, animation, event-detection, maple

There is a [maple code](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=applications/BouncingBall) for the bouncing ball on the given curve.

[image]

I tried to make this animation by using *Mathematica*

**Why does the following code not work?**

```
surf := Sin[x] + (0.2 Cos[4 x + Sin[4 x]]) - 0.2 x + 3;
v := {x'[t], y'[t]};
n1 = {-D[surf, x], 1};
n = Normalize[n1] /. x -> x[t];
c = 0.99;
vreflect = (-(1 + c) (v.n) n + v);

sol = NDSolveValue[{y''[t] == -9.81, x''[t] == 0,
x'[0] == 0,x[0] == 2, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 4.5, 
WhenEvent[Evaluate[y[t] == surf /. x -> x[t]], Evaluate[x'[t] -> vreflect[[1]]]], 
WhenEvent[Evaluate[y[t] == surf /. x -> x[t]], Evaluate[y'[t] -> vreflect[[2]]]]}, 
{x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];

Manipulate[
Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.013], 
Evaluate[Point[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}]]}, Axes -> True, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 5}}], 
Plot[surf, {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Gray], 
ImageSize -> 600], {t, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38927/how-to-simulate-the-true-reflective-movement-of-a-particle-bouncing-around-in-an

Comment: Also related: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ChaoticDynamicsOfABouncingBallInASinusoidalChannel/

Comment: Might help someone: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html -> Applications -> Bouncing ball.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two problems with the original post, both can be solved by referring to the documentation for [handling discontinuity events](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html):

1) As described under **Changing State Variables** section, the change in multiple state variables should either be attempted through a single rule with a list of variables or through multiple rules. Multiple rules have the nuance that the value of the first variable is set first, so the next rule will use this new value. To avoid this (and this is what the Maple example is doing through `temp` variable), we should use the single rule: `{{x'[t], y'[t]} -> Evaluate[vreflect]}`. A function used in both answers does the same, but this is shorter and less confusing.

2) In the subsection **Event Detection Methods**, there is a quote relevant to the problem:

> When the event function varies much more rapidly than the solutions
>   of the differential equation itself, the time steps may include many
>   crossings of an event function. This can be mitigated by including the
>   event function in the system as a dependent variable, using the
>   equation for the time derivative of the event shown above. This can be
>   done automatically using the option setting `"IntegrateEvent"->True` in
>   `WhenEvent`.

Note, that this is also the reason why [anderstood's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141217/44141) produces different results from Maple -- it simply misses the discontinuity events and falls through the terrain later. With the `"IntegrateEvent"->True`, the behavior is exactly as in the Maple example.

So, the updated code is:

```
surf := Sin[x] + (0.2 Cos[4 x + Sin[4 x]]) - 0.2 x + 3;
v := {x'[t], y'[t]};
n1 = {-D[surf, x], 1};
n = Normalize[n1] /. x -> x[t];
c = .99;
vreflect = -(1. + c) (v.n) n + v;

sol = NDSolveValue[{y''[t] == -9.81, x''[t] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
    x[0] == 2, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 4.5,
    WhenEvent[Evaluate[y[t] == surf /. x -> x[t]],
     {{x'[t], y'[t]} -> Evaluate[vreflect]},
     "IntegrateEvent" -> True
     ]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];

Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.013], 
    Evaluate[Point[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}]]}, Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 5}}], 
  Plot[surf, {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Gray], 
  ImageSize -> 600], {t, 0, 10, .01}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

The code won't work well for the lower values of `c`, but this can further be resolved by adjusting other parameters of the [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue.html) or [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html). For example, once the event has been detected, its location has to be determined. The `"LocationMethod"->"StepBegin"` works a little better than default `"Brent"` method, but further fine tuning is needed for very low values. Potentially, this can be solved using other equations of motion (i.e. Lagrangian).

Answer (score 14):

`WhenEvent` is triggered but does apparently not apply correctly the reflection. The following works (note that it uses only one `WhenEvent`). The `Print["bounce"]` is of course to be removed, I kept it just to check that the bouncing condition is triggered.

```
refl[x_?NumericQ, y_, xp_, yp_] := 
 vreflect /. x[t] -> x /. y[t] -> y /. x'[t] -> xp /. y'[t] -> yp

sol = NDSolveValue[{
    y''[t] == -9.81, x''[t] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
    x[0] == 2, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 4.5, 
    WhenEvent[
       Evaluate[y[t] == surf /. x -> x[t]], 
       Print["bounce"]; 
       {x'[t], y'[t]} -> refl[x[t], y[t], x'[t], y'[t]]]},
    {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Remark: the motion is different than that computed with Maple (especially after $t=4$). I guess that is because the system is chaotic so the small numerical differences between both lead to large discrepancies after a few bounces.

Answer (score 12):

reworked into vector form:

```
surf[x_] = Sin[x] + (0.2 Cos[4 x + Sin[4 x]]) - 0.2 x + 3;
n[x_] = Normalize[{-D[surf[x], x], 1}];
c = 0.99;
vreflect[v : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, 
         x : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] :=
            (-(1 + c) (v.n[x[[1]]]) n[x[[1]]] + v);
bounce[x : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] := (x[[2]] < surf[x[[1]]])
sol = First@NDSolve[{
     x''[t] == {0, -9.81},
     x'[0] == {0, 0},
     x[0] == {2, 4.5},
     WhenEvent[bounce[x[t]], x'[t] -> vreflect[x'[t], x[t]]]}, 
    x[t], {t, 0, 10}, MaxStepSize -> .01];
Show[{
  Plot[surf[x], {x, 0, 12},PlotStyle->Black,Filling->Axis],
  ParametricPlot[(x[t] /. sol), {t, 0, 10}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2, 5}]
```

[image]

`WhenEvent` does not work as well as I'd like here, I had to use an inequality and then need to force a small `MaxStepSize` or it occasionally misses.

Comment: With `c = 0.99` the heights of the peaks decrease slowly. If you choose a smaller number, like `0.5`, they decrease more quickly. But this simulation does not seem to work well for smaller `c`.

Comment: I think the physics is right: the total energy should be (almost) conserved at each bounce, which seems to be the case. When the horizontal velocity is high, the potential energy is low (curved parabolas have larger maxima than flat parabolas). You can check that if $c=1$, `vreflect` and `v` have the same norm (the reflection is an isometry for the kinetic energy).

Comment: right, i deleted my note about the physics.