# Raytracing using Regions & NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, graphics, finite-element-method, opencascade

I want to use geometric shapes in Mathematica to build complex shapes and use my raytracing algorithm on it. I have a working example where we can get the intersections from a combination of a `Cone[]` and `Cuboid[]`, e.g

```
shape1 = Cone[];
shape2 = Cuboid[];
(* add shapes in this list to make a more complicated shape *) 
shapes = {shape1, shape2};

(* this constains the shapes so the shape is considered as a whole *) 
constraints[shapes__] := 
 And[## & @@ (Not /@ 
      Through[(RegionMember[RegionIntersection@##] & @@@ 
          Subsets[{shapes}, {2}])@#]), 
   RegionMember[RegionUnion @@ (RegionBoundary /@ {shapes})]@#] &

direction = {-0.2, -0.2, -1};
point = {0.5, 0.5, 1.5};

line = HalfLine[{point, point + direction}];

intersections[l_, s__] := 
 NSolve[# ∈ l && constraints[s][#], #] &@({x, y, z}[[;; RegionEmbeddingDimension[l]]])

(* find intersection *) 
intersection = intersections[line, ##] & @@ shapes;

points = Point[{x, y, z}] /. intersection;

Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.2], shapes}, line, {Red, points}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True]
```

This works well, and we get the external intersections as we expect.

[image]

Now, let us try to take the difference between two shapes, modelling something like

```
square = Cuboid[];
ball = Ball[{0, 0, 1}, 1];
Region[RegionDifference[square, ball]]
```

[image]

```
shapes = {RegionDifference[square, ball]};
direction = {0, 0, -1};
point = {0.5, 0.5, 5};
line = HalfLine[{point, point + direction}];
intersection = intersections[line, ##] & @@ shapes
```

Does not work, with an error that the constraints are "*not a quantified system of equations and inequalities*"...even though the constraints look fine

```
constraints[shapes]
(* (##1 &) @@ 
   Not /@ Through[
     Apply[RegionMember[RegionIntersection[##1]] &, 
       Subsets[{{BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}], 
            Ball[{0, 0, 1}, 1]}]}}, {2}], {1}][#1]] && 
  RegionMember[
    RegionUnion @@ 
     RegionBoundary /@ {{BooleanRegion[#1 && ! #2 &, {Cuboid[{0, 0, 
            0}], Ball[{0, 0, 1}, 1]}]}}][#1] & *)
```

Comment: Just to give you starting ideas: have you seen [Quilez's treatment](https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm)?

Comment: No, but this looks very helpful indeed.

Comment: [Tim Laska's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219645/42264) shows some great 3D raytracing using complicated shapes. There might be something there that can help if you haven't already seen it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but an alternate approach.  You could create a list of primitives and a build function that contains the Computational Solid Geometry (CSG).

```
square = Cuboid[];
ball = Ball[{0, 0, 1}, 1];
buildList = {square, ball};
(* Constraints *)
buildFn = ¬ #2 ∧ #1 &;
reg = Region[
   Style[BooleanRegion[buildFn, buildList], Opacity[0.5], Green]];
direction = {0, 0, -1};
point = {0.5, 0.5, 5};
line = HalfLine[{point, point + direction}];
rint = Region[RegionIntersection[reg, line], 
  BaseStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]; 
intpoints = Point[Transpose@RegionBounds@rint];
Show[reg, rint, Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, intpoints}]]
```

[image: Difference]

Here is how it would look for the initial case:

```
shape1 = Cone[];
shape2 = Cuboid[];
buildList = {shape1, shape2};
(* Constraints *)
buildFn = #2 || #1 &;
reg = Region[
   Style[BooleanRegion[buildFn, buildList], Opacity[0.5], Green]];
direction = {-0.2, -0.2, -1};
point = {0.5, 0.5, 1.5};
line = HalfLine[{point, point + direction}];
rint = Region[RegionIntersection[reg, line], 
  BaseStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]; intpoints = 
 Point[Transpose@RegionBounds@rint];
Show[reg, rint, Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Red, intpoints}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Initial Case]

## Update to Increase Speed

@Tomi mentioned in the comments that speed is a concern.  As addressed in my answer to the MSE question [Why is Ray Tracing Slow?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219645/61809) I created a solver that that used the fast region functions [`RegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistance.html)and [`RegionNormal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionNormal.html) to solve a 1000 multiple bounce ray traces in 3D geometry including geometry produced by a commercial CAD package.  I will adapt that approach to look at the bouncing of single ray.

### Set up the Geometry

The [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html) does a pretty good job at constructing geometry that snaps to features while keeping the triangle count down.  The following workflow will create the the initial Box-Cone geometry.

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
pp = Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[pp];
axis = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, axis];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep];
Show[Graphics3D[{{Red, pp}, {Blue, Thick, Arrow[axis]}}], 
 bmesh["Wireframe"], Boxed -> False]
cu = OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]];
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[cu, sweep];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[union];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
mrd = MeshRegion[bmesh, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

### Solve a Single Ray Trace

The following workflow solves for a single ray trace.  Each bounce will cause the ray to attenuate the representative sphere size by 10%.  This solves and plots quickly.

```
(* Set up Region Operators on Differenced Geometry *)
rdf = RegionDistance[mrd];
rnf = RegionNearest[mrd];
(* Setup and run simulation *)
(* Time Increment *)
dt = 0.01;
(* Collision Margin *)
margin = (1 + dt) dt;
(* Conditional Particle Advancer *)
advance[r_, x_, v_, c_] := 
 Block[{xnew = x + dt v}, {rdf[xnew], xnew, v, c}] /; r > margin
advance[r_, x_, v_, c_] := 
 Block[{xnew = x , vnew = v, normal = Normalize[x - rnf[x]]},
   vnew = Normalize[v - 2 v.normal normal];
   xnew += dt vnew;
   {rdf[xnew], xnew, vnew, c + 1}] /; r <= margin
(* Starting Point for Emission *)
sp = {0, 0, 0.25};
nparticles = 1;
ntimesteps = 800;
tabres = Table[
   NestList[
    advance @@ # &, {rdf[sp], 
     sp, { Cos[2 Pi #[[1]]] Sin[Pi #[[2]]], 
        Sin[ Pi #[[2]]] Sin[2 Pi #[[1]]], Cos[ Pi #[[2]]]} &@
      First@RandomReal[1, {1, 2}], 0}, ntimesteps], {i, 1, 
    nparticles}];
epilog[i_] := {ColorData["Rainbow", (#4 - 1)/10], 
    Sphere[#2, 0.04 0.9^#4]} & @@@ tabres[[i]]
Graphics3D[{White, EdgeForm[Thin], Opacity[0.25], mrd, Opacity[1]}~
  Join~epilog[1], Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> RegionBounds[mrd], 
 ViewPoint -> {-1.7742436871276688`, 1.5459832360779067`, 
   2.431459473742817`}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0.052110700162003136`, -0.06948693625348555`, 
   0.9962208794332359`}]
```

[image: Cone Box Single Ray Trace]

## A More Complex Case

The following produces a shape with concavity that could find rays that intersect but would be blocked by an intervening surface.  Because the solver use a fine time increment, these intersections are not found because the collision of the intervening surface is detected.

```
pp = Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}];
shape = OpenCascadeShape[pp];
axis = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, axis];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep];
Show[Graphics3D[{{Red, pp}, {Blue, Thick, Arrow[axis]}}], 
 bmesh["Wireframe"], Boxed -> False]
cu = OpenCascadeShape[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]];
ball = OpenCascadeShape[Ball[{1/2, 1/2, 2.4}, 1.5]];
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[cu, sweep, ball];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[union];
groups = bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@ colors]]
mrd = MeshRegion[bmesh, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
(* Set up Region Operators on Differenced Geometry *)
rdf = RegionDistance[mrd];
rnf = RegionNearest[mrd];
(* Setup and run simulation *)
(* Time Increment *)
dt = 0.01;
(* Collision Margin *)
margin = (1 + dt) dt;
(* Conditional Particle Advancer *)
advance[r_, x_, v_, c_] := 
 Block[{xnew = x + dt v}, {rdf[xnew], xnew, v, c}] /; r > margin
advance[r_, x_, v_, c_] := 
 Block[{xnew = x , vnew = v, normal = Normalize[x - rnf[x]]},
   vnew = Normalize[v - 2 v.normal normal];
   xnew += dt vnew;
   {rdf[xnew], xnew, vnew, c + 1}] /; r <= margin
(* Starting Point for Emission *)
sp = {0, 0, 0.5};
nparticles = 1;
ntimesteps = 1600;
(*tabres= Table[NestList[advance@@#&,{rdf[sp],sp,{ Cos[2 Pi #[[1]]] \
Sin[Pi #[[2]]],Sin[ Pi #[[2]]] Sin[2 Pi #[[1]]], Cos[ Pi \
#[[2]]]}&@First@RandomReal[1,{1,2}],0},ntimesteps],{i,1,nparticles}];*)


tabres = Table[
   NestList[
    advance @@ # &, {rdf[sp], 
     sp, { Cos[2 Pi #[[1]]] Sin[Pi #[[2]]], 
        Sin[ Pi #[[2]]] Sin[2 Pi #[[1]]], Cos[ Pi #[[2]]]} &@
      First@{{0.3788624698388783`, 0.8749177935911279`}}, 0}, 
    ntimesteps], {i, 1, nparticles}];
epilog[i_] := {ColorData["Rainbow", (#4 - 1)/12], 
    Sphere[#2, 0.04 0.9^#4]} & @@@ tabres[[i]]
Graphics3D[{White, EdgeForm[Thin], Opacity[0.25], mrd, Opacity[1]}~
  Join~epilog[1], Boxed -> False, PlotRange -> RegionBounds[mrd], 
 ViewPoint -> {-3.102894731729034`, -1.0062787100553268`, 
   0.8996929706836663`}, 
 ViewVertical -> {-0.34334064946409365`, -0.07403103185215265`, 
   0.93628874005217`}]
```

[image: Concave Surface]

Comment: The disadvantage is that `RegionIntersection[]` is much slower than `NSolve[]`. Hence your particle advancer solution, which works very well - but I was hoping to be able to use the capabilities of `NSolve[]`.

Comment: I think I have identified the problem: posted a new question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222199/finding-the-regionmemberfunction-of-the-boundary-of-a-regiondifference?noredirect=1#comment565699_222199

Comment: @Tomi Thank you for the accept and your kind words.  Just a word of caution about OpenCascade.  Since it is a CAD package, you probably need to avoid non-manifold geometry (i.e., zero volume sections).  Also, I may have discovered bug with the Cone primitive and that is why I revolved a triangle around the axis.  I will contact support when I have time.

Answer (score 5):

Tim Laska's solution is excellent. It is fast and accurate. However, for completeness, I have a solution for the `NDSolve` solution, where we can find the intersections instead of the (excellent) particle advancer (i.e. just jump between the intersections instead of advance).

By using the solution from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222199/finding-the-regionmemberfunction-of-the-boundary-of-a-regiondifference?noredirect=1#comment565699_222199)

```
line = HalfLine[{0.5, 0.5, 2}, {0, 0, -1}]


intersection = 
 NSolve[{x, y, z} \[Element] line && 
   RegionMember[
     regionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]][{x, y, 
     z}], {x, y, z}]

regionBoundary[reg_?RegionQ] := 
 Module[{x, y, z}, 
  ImplicitRegion[
   CylindricalDecomposition[RegionMember[reg, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}, 
    "Boundary"], {x, y, z}]]

Show[{Region[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]], 
  Region[Style[Point[{x, y, z}] /. intersection[[1]], Red]], 
  Region[Style[Point[{x, y, z}] /. intersection[[2]], Red]]}]
```

[image]

Intersections highlighted in red.

Answer (score 2):

This issue could be solved by "sphere tracing", it's similar to Tim's particle advancer" and reasonable fast which will converge in a very small amount of steps.

```
RayIntersect[ray_, region_, maxIteration_, maxRadius_, 
  radiusThreshold_] := Module[{ rnf, RegionMarcher, result},
  rnf = RegionNearest[region];
  RegionMarcher[orig_, radius_, step_] := 
   Block[{next, closestPoint, advOp, radiusCurrent},
    closestPoint = rnf[orig];
    advOp = 
     If[Dot[closestPoint - orig, dir /. ray] > 0, 
      Subtract, {a, b} |-> b - a];
    radiusCurrent =  Max[Abs[advOp @@ {closestPoint , orig}]] // N;
    next = orig + radiusCurrent * (dir /. ray);
    Sow[{orig, next, Abs[radiusCurrent], advOp, step + 1}];
    {next, Abs[radiusCurrent], step + 1}
    ] ;
  
  result = 
   NestWhile[RegionMarcher @@ # &, {origin /. ray, 1, 0}, 
    e |-> (e[[2]] < maxRadius && e[[2]] > radiusThreshold && 
       e[[3]] < maxIteration)];
  
  If[result[[2]] >= maxRadius || result[[3]] >= maxIteration, None, 
   result[[1]]]
  ]
RayIntersect[ray_, region_] := 
 RayIntersect[ray, region, 10, 256, 0.01]
```

And the result:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Blue, 
  DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[square, ball]], 
  Arrow[{point, point + direction}], Red, 
  Map[(e |-> { Sphere[e[[1]], e[[3]]]}), 
   Reap[RayIntersect[{origin -> point, dir -> direction}, 
        RegionDifference[square, ball]]] // Rest // First // First]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image: sphere tarcing]