# Finding the `RegionMemberFunction[]` of the boundary of a `RegionDifference[]`

Tags: regions

```
RegionMember[RegionBoundary[Cuboid[]]]
```

Works, but

```
RegionMember[RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]]
```

Returns nothing, even though the region `RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]`  is a `Region[]`

```
RegionQ[RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]]
(* True *)
```

And it even `RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]` looks like a region!

```
Region[RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: `Region[RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]]` works for me. Is your syntax `RegionMember[RegionUnion[RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]]]` correct?

Comment: Try finding the `RegionMemberFunction[]` of it by using `RegionMember[]` - that seems to be issue...I noticed the title was misleading - so I have edited it.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. `RegionMember` should not be returning `{}`.

Comment: I mean `RegionUnion[RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]]`. Hope I am clear.

Comment: (And btw you don't need to use `RegionUnion` on one argument.)

Comment: Thanks - edited for clarity

Comment: `RegionMember[
 RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]], {1, 2, 3}]` fails: the input is returned instead of `False`. This is a two-dimensional object in three dimensions.

Comment: `RegionEmbeddingDimension[
 RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]]` returns 3...how can the region membership test be less than 3 in this case? Also `RegionDimension[RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]]` returns 2 as we would expect.

Comment: I have in mind `RegionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]` is too hard for the `Member` command. However, in this case the input should be returned.

Comment: Putting the graphics into a `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]` seems to work, which I've posted as a partial answer. But if this is a bug, should I report it?...is there a meta post which advises the best way to proceed?

Comment: I think you should report it as a bug to https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find a workaround for semialgebraic regions through `CylindricalDecomposition`.

```
regionBoundary[reg_?RegionQ] := 
  Module[{x,y,z},
    ImplicitRegion[
      CylindricalDecomposition[RegionMember[reg, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}, "Boundary"], 
      {x, y, z}
    ]
  ]

RegionMember[regionBoundary[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], Ball[]]]] // Head
```

> ```
> RegionMemberFunction
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Not really a solution, but a work around is to wrap the shapes in `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[]`:

```
RegionMember[RegionDifference[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[]], BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[]]]]
```

Returns a `RegionMemberFunction`

Comment: Also `RegionMember[
 RegionDifference[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[]], 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[]]], {1, 2, 3.1}]` performs `False`.